# Two Level-Slide Menu Like Facebook iOS (iPhone Application)

Tags: ios

How i can achieve two Level Slide Menu.I read many articles but all the Slide menu are just with one Level.

Comment: You haven't included your screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you haven't search any thing, 
There are Lots of Controls  available,

Here are Some Good Controls:

[SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

[ECSlidingViewController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ecslidingviewcontroller--2)

[MMDrawerController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mmdrawercontroller--2)

[JASidePanels](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jasidepanels)

[PKRevealController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pkrevealcontroller)

[MFSideMenu](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mfsidemenu)

Comment: Ya sure..I want two level menu,Not one level.I want different menus which is context sensitive.Each page have different item menus..Not in home page..

Comment: Brother for that you have to do some programming your self, we are not here to write code for you.

Comment: The examples which is given by u is easily i can find it from google. i don't need ur help for finding this..My scenario is quite strange that is why i asked u

Comment: Good so what is than problem?

Comment: The examples which is given by u is easily i can find it from google. i don't need ur help for finding this..My scenario is quite strange that is why i asked u –

Comment: @VipinKVIas: as i say for that you have to do yourself, use UITAbleView+UINAvigationController for that,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) for this. And here's a good [***tutorial***](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)
 on how to do it,

Comment: Ya sure..I want two level menu,Not one level.I want different menus which is context sensitive.Each page have different item menus..Not in home page..